# List as O(log(n))

Tags: java, algorithm, list, arraylist, data-structures

I have to make a data structure with certain conditions.

First these 4 functions must be in O(log(n)):

```
insert(Object o)  
insert(int index, Object o)  
delete(int index)  
update(int index, Object o)
```

Second: The data structure must implement `java.util.List`

My issue is with the O(log(n)) and the List. There are a lot of trees that can do the operation in O(log(n)) (like BST, Red-Black Tree, AVL Tree), but     how can these trees be indexed and how can the insert be anywhere?

Setting this up as only a list does bring up issues.
`java.util.List` has these implementing classes:
`AbstractList`, `AbstractSequentialList`, `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `Stack`, `Vector`

Most of these classes have methods of O(1) and O(1) < O(log(n)), but there is always a method that is O(n). Example the ArrayList has a remove of O(n).

Does anyone have any advise or approaches to this problem?

Basically, I am looking for a data structure that I'll fulfill those requirements.

Comment: You're a bit too early in the programming process to be coming here for help. You need to ask a much more specific question ideally showing the code you've written.

Comment: Hint: a tree can be seen as a list if you traverse it in order. A balanced binary tree with item's _index_ as the ordering value, and an Object payload in each node, would work; basically it'd be a `TreeMap<Integer, Object>`, possibly with an added check preventing non-contiguous indexes. (If the indexes are required to be contiguous, `delete(int)` won't be O(log(n)), though.)

Comment: What about sorted arrays? Should be O(log(n))

Comment: @9000 yeah that was my issue with the delete(int) not being O(log(n))..

Comment: @9000 Not sure how you can implement a list with random access in your method. If an element is currently mapped at 3, and one uses `add(3,object)`, then the element that was at 3 is supposed to be shifted to 4. How do you do that in O(log n)?

Comment: @PierrePascalLindenberg A sorted arrays insert would be O(n) since all elements must be shifted. This is the issue, most data structures fulfill 3 out of the 4 Big-O requirements. Thank you for the input though

Comment: Implementing List does not mean it has to be one of the existing implementations.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Indeed, it cannot be O(log n) with the naive tree-based approach!

Answer (score 3):

An [indexable skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist) seems to fit the bill: inserts and deletes are O(log n), and index access for `update` is *also* O(log n).

Answer (score 2):

> My issue is with the O(log(n)) and the List. There are a lot of trees that can do the operation in O(log(n)) (like BST, Red-Black Tree, AVL Tree), but how can these trees be indexed and how can the insert be anywhere?

If you just include a `subtreeSize` field in your `Node` class, and keep it up-to-date as you insert/delete/rotate/etc. (which involves some bookkeeping, but won't affect your asymptotic complexities), then you can infer the index of any given node by the size of its left-child's subtree and those of its ancestors.

Your result will be a bit different from those, though, in that those trees are all sorted, whereas you just want to preserve the order specified by the insert operations. So while you should definitely have those in the back of your mind as you think about keeping your tree balanced, don't let yourself be led astray by irrelevant aspects.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a Hashmap using the List. That way your insert, delete, and search are all `O(1)`. A simple approach could be making a list that contains linked lists and then coming up with a good hash function to minimize collisions. Then all you have to do is actually coding these functions and you will hopefully have the performance requirements you need (just use efficient algorithms).

Comment: Yes I see. I think I can come up with a solution that would be 3log(n) which is still O(log(n) thank you

Comment: This doesn't work, because if your hash-keys are the indices, then insertion involves updating all subsequent indices, which requires worst-case O(n) time.

Comment: There could be a mapping to indices, separate from the hashmap. Some way to keep track of the indices for each entry in the hashmap. Then this mapping is updated whenever a delete or insert is performed. Maybe another hashmap that maps indices and keys?

Comment: @Developer: No, that doesn't help.

Comment: I don't think you can say that until you try :)

Comment: I'm making a array of arrays where the first array would hold 1, 2nd would hold 2, 3rd would hold 4, 4th would hold 8 and ect the worst case add would be 2log(n) (size of the last level of filled) or remove which would also 2logn at worst case. So this would still fit my O(log n ) requirements.

Comment: @mikedaabeast: That's not right. Suppose you have 15 elements (1+2+4+8) and need to delete the eighth element (meaning, the first element of the fourth array). Then you need to shift seven elements. (More generally, if you have 2^n-1 elements, then deleting the 2^(n-1)th element will involve shifting 2^(n-1)-1 elements.) So your worst-case deletion complexity is O(n), not O(log n).

Comment: Sorry I mean array of linked list, not of array.

Comment: Let me know how it goes, I believe in you @mikedaabeast

Comment: @mikedaabeast: It takes O(k) time to iterate to the kth element of a linked list; so if you're storing elements in linked lists of length up to O(n), then inserting/deleting/updating elements by index will require O(n) time in the worst case.

Comment: Yes but no level will have n. At the biggest level, the size will be 2log(n)

Comment: @mikedaabeast: You said that each list would hold twice as many elements as the one before. That means that the last list, if full, will hold more than half the elements of the list -- which is in Θ(n). (Incidentally, if you want to be sure I'll see your replies, then you need to write `@ruakh` so that the site will notify me of them. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment.)