# List with O(log n) indexOf operation

Tags: vector, indexing, data-structures, rust, time-complexity

I'm looking for a data structure that can store a list of elements, while also enabling sub-`O(n)` lookup of the index given an element and element given an index, as well as insertion at an index.

Elements are dense (integers `0..n`) and unique, but unsorted.

For example, in Rust this data structure would be used like so:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut list = List::new();
    list.extend(vec![5, 2, 0, 4, 1, 3]);

    assert_eq!(list.get(2), 0);
    assert_eq!(list.get(3), 4);
    assert_eq!(list.index_of(0), 2);
    assert_eq!(list.index_of(4), 3);
}
```

`O(√n)` operations would be acceptable, `O(log n)` would be ideal. I'm drawing a blank here; any help much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List as O(log(n))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560005/list-as-ologn)

Comment: Thanks @Mihir, unfortunately not as elements are unsorted but their order must be maintained, which I think rules out the indexable skip list. A tree storing `subtreeSize` at each node might be part of the solution, though I'm drawing a blank as to what the rest looks like.

Comment: @Stargateur I gave an example of usage in Rust, and that's what I'll be using this in, but any language would do.

Comment: If an element were to be removed from this data structure–I assume that is a possibility?–should the indices greater than that of the removed element change and decrement by one?

Comment: @Jason Yes indeed.

Comment: What are other restrictions? E.g., can you perform some kind of processing upon adding to  the list or removing from it? Or you are starting from a given list?

Comment: The three operations I need sub-`O(n)` are: lookup index -> element, lookup element -> index, insert element at index. Removal is a bonus. Besides it being practical I don't think there are any other relevant restrictions.

Comment: @Stargateur It is possible for all three operations to be `O(log n)`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Stargateur I found https://github.com/masyamandev/indexable-set which achieves this.

Comment: @Stargateur No, the AVL tree is only ordered with respect to the indices, so it is indeed also an indexed list of elements. Thus searching, inserting and removing by index is O(log n). The clever bit is finding the index of an element, for which a separate hash map is used. The OP is correct.

Comment: @Max That's an excellent question, and the answer you found on github is most intriguing. Please consider adding an answer yourself with a description of the data structure, in case the link expires at some point.

Comment: @Stargateur I checked it, and it seems valid. I wouldn't have thought it's possible myself, but it's actually really simple and clever. And certainly an AVL tree with O(log n) operations is a lot more efficient in practice than a simple list with O(n) operations for realistically large n. A hash map simply doesn't support the operations required. I do hope the OP self-answers this question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This library](https://github.com/masyamandev/indexable-set) provides an "`IndexedTreeListSet`" data structure which implements the three operations required in `O(log n)`:

- lookup index -> element
- lookup element -> index (aka index of)
- insert element at index

It does this, as Mo B. [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65048598/list-with-olog-n-indexof-operation?noredirect=1#comment115011262_65048598), with an ancilliary hashmap to map elements to their node in the tree, which is then traversed upwards to the root. As each node in the tree contains its relative index, at the root the absolute index can be calculated.

I switched from a naïve approach (with `O(n)` inserts) to this, and the reduction of wall execution time for inserts (which occur ~100 times per second) from ~100ms to ~1ms.

Comment: Out of interest, have you implemented this in Rust, and if so, is it open source? I was thinking about having a go at it out of interest and learning more about this data structure.

Comment: @Jason I have indeed implemented it in Rust but unfortunately I cannot open source it (yet!)

Answer (score 0):

Would maintaining a separate `Vec<T>` and `HashMap<usize, T>` be adequate? The `HashMap` would have a [lower lookup time](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/index.html#maps) than `O(log n)` with it being `O(1)~`.

Downsides of this seem to be that:

- You would have to store both the `Vec<T>` and `HashMap<usize, T>` in memory.
- Upon removal of an element, you will have to decrement the indices for each element in the `HashMap<usize, T>` as well, possibly making removal costly.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct List {
    index_to_value: Vec<i32>,
    value_to_index: HashMap<i32, usize>,
}

impl List {
    fn new<I>(index_to_value: I) -> Self
    where
        I: Into<Vec<i32>>,
    {
        let index_to_value = index_to_value.into();
        let value_to_index = index_to_value
            .iter()
            .copied()
            .enumerate()
            .map(|(index, value)| (value, index))
            .collect();

        Self {
            index_to_value,
            value_to_index,
        }
    }

    fn get(&self, n: usize) -> Option<i32> {
        self.index_to_value.get(n).copied()
    }

    fn index_of(&self, i: i32) -> Option<usize> {
        self.value_to_index.get(&i).copied()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let list = List::new(vec![5, 2, 0, 4, 1, 3]);

    assert_eq!(list.get(2), Some(0));
    assert_eq!(list.get(3), Some(4));
    assert_eq!(list.index_of(0), Some(2));
    assert_eq!(list.index_of(4), Some(3));
}
```

Comment: It seems you'll need to increment indices for each element in the HashMap upon insertion also? Making insertion `O(n)` as well as removal.

Comment: Ah, correct, I glossed over "insertion at an index".